# How can I get shell.searchandler to push its own text?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to push the text from my **Shell.SearchHandler** to a command.

I have built this with **SearchBar** , but i need this to work in the **Shell.SearchHandler**

```
<Shell.SearchHandler >        
 <SearchHandler  x:Name="searchBar"
               Placeholder="Search..."
               Command="{Binding PerformSearch}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="LightGray" />
 </Shell.SearchHandler>
```

And in my View model

```
    public ICommand PerformSearch => new Command<string>((string query) =>
    {
      //do work
    });
```

The command does execute but the query param is always null.

How can I get the text that was entered into the searchandler to be posted to the binding command?

Comment: You can set the  `Query`,. `Query="{Binding xxx,Mode=OneWayToSource}"` ,and get the value in ViewModel .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}"

After having a look at **[SearchHandler reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/search#searchhandler-reference)** document as follow :

- **Query**, of type string, the user entered text in the search box.

The reason is that `SearchHandler` not contains `Text` property .You should replace it with **Query** , then it can work .

```
<Shell.SearchHandler >        
 <SearchHandler  x:Name="searchBar"
               Placeholder="Search..."
               Command="{Binding PerformSearch}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding Query, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}" 
               TextColor="Black" 
               BackgroundColor="LightGray" />
 </Shell.SearchHandler>
```

Note : Also can [Custom a SearchHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/search#consume-a-searchhandler) to monitor Query changed if needed .

Creare a `MySearchHandler` :

```
public class MySearchHandler : SearchHandler
{
    protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
        {
            ItemsSource = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("search string " + newValue);
            // here you can add code to deal with the viewmodel 
            //ItemsSource = MonkeyData.Monkeys
            .Where(monkey => monkey.Name.ToLower().Contains(newValue.ToLower()))
            .ToList<Animal>();
        }
    }
}
```

In `Xaml` :

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Controls">
    <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <controls:MonkeySearchHandler Placeholder="Enter search term"
                                      ShowsResults="true"
                                      DisplayMemberName="Name" />
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Here is [the official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) for reference , this need some time to research it.

Comment: Thank you I am still very new to Xamarin, would you by chance know of a resource that shows how to use custom search handler in mvvm style?

Comment: @Jack Okey ,  I will update in answer later,and more detail info is my shared document ,

Comment: Based on answer, I can get the result in ViewModel. But the result didn't populate in search suggestion area.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5783 This issue is already posted here. Anybody knows the update?